# Google earth plugin key pressed event javascript hookup

Tags: javascript, google-earth-plugin

Is there any way to receive a key-press event from the Google earth plugin.
I saw that `GEWindow` has a `click` event for the mouse but I need to capture the key pressing in any form.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately not, there is a five year old feature request for this functionality...
https://code.google.com/p/earth-api-samples/issues/detail?id=53

There is a workaround discussed in the comments, but it is far from perfect.

Anyhow, if you 'star' the request then you should receive updates on its status (just don't hold your breath!)